# Remove lines from image - matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I found this microscope image and I wonder what are the ways to remove the white lines from it using Matlab?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fill them with some pixel intensity value or remove them altogether and make them black for example? Is that a picture from a hemocytometer?

Comment: It would be great if it will be possible to or remove them altogether and make them black. Yes, the picture from a hemocytometer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple morphological operations combined with [`roifill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html) to get a preliminary result:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nBqS.png');
img = im2double(img(:,:,1));
bw = img > .8; %// get a mask of grid lines (approx.)
bw = imdilate( imerode( bw, ones(2) ), ones(4) ); %// mask for roifill
nImg = roifill( img, bw );
```

Resulting with
  [image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I paint the lines in black?

Comment: @user2916044 try `nImg = img.*(img<.8);`

Comment: Thanks. As it also effect the cells is there a way to black only the lines?

Comment: If you want something more sophisticated than simple threshold, you'll need to work harder. try graphcuts.

Comment: Thanks. Were can I find more information suitable for a beginner in image analysis?